# How to set the coordinates of a rect with get_rect() or Rect()?

Tags: python, pygame, rect

This is an example that works:
It loads a red figure at the bottom of my screen. So far so good, but
I want to load the figure at specific coordinates like 700 (x-axis) and 100 (y-axis).

```
import pygame


class Figure:

    def __init__(self, screen2):
        """Initialize the figure and set its starting position."""
        self.screen2 = screen2

        # Load the Red figure image and get its rect.
        self.redplayer = pygame.image.load('Images/redplayer.bmp')
        self.rectredplayer = self.redplayer.get_rect()
        self.screen2_rect = screen2.get_rect()

        # Start each new redplayer at the bottom center of the screen.
        self.rectredplayer.centerx = self.screen2_rect.centerx
        self.rectredplayer.bottom = self.screen2_rect.bottom

    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the red player figure at its current location."""
        self.screen2.blit(self.redplayer, self.rectredplayer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the topleft coords in this way:

```
self.rectredplayer.x = 700
self.rectredplayer.y = 100
# Or just:
self.rectredplayer.topleft = (700, 100)
```

To set the center of the rect to the desired coords:

```
self.rectredplayer.center = (700, 100)
```

Or use the other [rect attributes](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html):

```
x,y
top, left, bottom, right
topleft, bottomleft, topright, bottomright
midtop, midleft, midbottom, midright
center, centerx, centery
```

You can also pass the coords directly to `Surface.get_rect`:

```
self.rectredplayer = self.redplayer.get_rect(topleft=(700, 100))
```